# Why do wind power plants have just 3 blades?

Tags: energy, aerodynamics, air

Why do wind power plants have just 3 blades? It seems that adding more blades would increase the area that interacts with the wind and gather more energy.

[image]

<sub>(Image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Windfarm_-_geograph.org.uk_-_150717.jpg).)</sub>

Comment: Short answer by (same) Wikipedia: *3-bladed turbines have high tip speeds of over 320 km/h (200 mph), high efficiency, and low torque ripple, which contribute to good reliability*

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen 2-bladed ones as well.

Comment: Also see Wikipedia: [_Blade count_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_turbine_design#Blade_count).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just easier, i.e. less expensive, to build and maintain them that way. There exist alternative designs that are more efficient but also more difficult (= more expensive) to build, put up and maintain. You can check those out [via this link](http://www.popularmechanics.com/science/energy/solar-wind/4324331).

Comment: why down-vote? so this isn't correct?